# extract text from the last special character in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

EXample:

```
*AB|USA|California|los angles_backup
*AB|USA|California_backup
```

Questions: I need the word after the last pipe(|). In the first example, I need only Los angles and for 2nd example, I need only California.

Comment: Can you clarify what significance the '_backup' has? In your example you say your desired output excludes it, but you don't mention it explicitly. Does every record have that text, and it needs to be excluded?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```vba
Function GetLastPartAfterPipe(str As String) As String
    tmp = Split(str, "|")
    GetLastPartAfterPipe = tmp(UBound(tmp))
End Function
```

and B1=GetLastPartAfterPipe(A1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using built-in functions only:

- first calculate location of last `|`:
  `=MAX(IF(MID(A1,ROW(OFFSET(A1,1,1,LEN(A1))),1)="|",ROW(OFFSET(A1,1,1,LEN(A1))),""))`
  This is an array formula, so press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after typing it
- second you can get your desired text:
  `=MID(A1,B1+1,LEN(A1)-B1)`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since there is a '_backup' at the end of everything it might be best to do this in two steps vs. making a single very long formula.

Step one in `B` to strip out the data after the last pipe:

`=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|",""))),1))`

Then Step two in `C`:

`=MID(B1,1,FIND("_",B1)-1)`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|",REPT(" ",99)),99)),FIND("_",TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|",REPT(" ",99)),99)))-1)
```

- `TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|",REPT(" ",99)),99))` will return the last pipe-separated substring.
- `LEFT(last_substring,FIND("_", last_substring)-1)` then returns the part of that substring prior to the underscore.

[image]

Comment: the TRIM command worked perfectly